# Ansible fetch file from remote and keep on control node?

Tags: ansible

Let's say I have this compile role and it's last task fetches the compiled binaries from a build server.

```
- name: "fetch release tar"
  fetch:
    src: "{{ project_path }}/rel/{{ app_name }}/releases/{{ app_version }}/{{ app_name }}.tar.gz"
    dest: "~/releases/"
    flat: yes
```

Once this role completes, Ansible seems to clean up the release directory, presumably because these files are temporary? Is there a way fetch can make this permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tilde expansion](http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells#brace-tilde-cmd-pathname-expansion) is handled by the login shell (bash, zsh, ksh, etc.). Ansible does not perform any tilde expansion on its own, so using one in the `dest` parameter as you have results in undefined behavior.

You should either hardcode a full path for your destination, or as an alternative you can make use of the `expanduser` [filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters) that was added in Ansible 1.5 to perform this tilde expansion inside your playbook.